# Searching python lists with loops and conditionals

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, conditional-statements

```
def ListCreate(*args):
    items = none
    for i in range(len(args)-1,-1,-1):
        items = join(args[i], items)
    return items

a = ListCreate(1,2,3,4,5,6)
b = ListCreate(20150602, 20150603, 20150604, 20150605, 20150606, 20150607)
```

Lists in python are ordered, so I would like `element 0` in list a to correspond with `element 0` in list b.
 i.e.

```
 (1,20150602)(2,20150603)(3,20150604) 
  #etc
```

Now, I'd like to create a search loop that asks `if a(n)==a(n+1) and b(n+1) - b(n) <= 3` ...print all elements where conditions remain true.

Comment: So... you want `zip`? Also, why do `a = ListCreate(1,2,3)` when you can do `a = [1,2,3]`?

Comment: I assume this is part of some code for creating linked-lists, not regular Python lists. Probably a programming excercise. If this is the case, it is pretty much impossible to answer the question without seeing more of how your lists are structured, e.g. what `join` does.

Comment: To set up the possibility of creating a list of the results using the ListCreate operation.........Yes, having the lists "zipped" is what I'm looking for as well.

Comment: Essentially just trying to search LIST1 with conditions and if true search LIST2 with conditions......if true, place element in a new list.....continue until all elements have been tested

Comment: Actually it kind of looks like you want [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) but it's hard to tell what you're really trying to do.

Comment: Tobias.....join just gives me the ability to prepend elements into a given list later as the data grows.

Comment: Two-Bit.....I could use enumerate, but my list1 already has integers that correspond to list2 integers......zip seems more effective

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to understand your desired output, but this is my best guess:

```
        In [39]:

a = [1,1,3,4,4,6]
b = [20150602, 20150603, 20150604, 20150605, 20150606, 20150607]
c = zip(a, b)

print c  
for i in range(0, len(c)-1):
    if c[i][0] == c[i+1][0] and c[i+1][1] - c[i][1] <= 3:
        print c[i]



[(1, 20150602), (1, 20150603), (3, 20150604), (4, 20150605), (4, 20150606), (6, 20150607)]
(1, 20150602)
(4, 20150605)
```

Comment: the first iteration you had worked better, but thank you so much. If I had any rep, I'd upvote

Comment: Thanks @fORzoas.  I updated code to first version. Please accept the answer if it was helpful.